# Change attributes of cloned table tr

Tags: jquery

I have cloned a tr of table.
I want to change the td's attributes

```
<tr style="cursor:move" id="CloneThisTR">
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group" id="TP_tr_dest_from_city_1">
                            {{{ Form::select('TP_tr_dest_from_city_multicity', [''=>'* From City']+$TR_FromIndianCities , null,array('id'=>'TR_FromCities_1','class'=>'form-control requestDiv','name'=>'TP_tr_dest_from_city_multicity_1','title'=>'Enter travel from city',)) }}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group" id="TP_tr_dest_to_city_1">
                            {{{ Form::select('TP_tr_dest_to_city_multicity', [''=>'* To City']+$TR_FromIndianCities , null,array('id'=>'TR_ToCities_1','class'=>'form-control requestDiv','name'=>'TP_tr_dest_to_city_multicity','title'=>'Enter travel from city',)) }}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group" id="TP_tr_from_date_1">
                            {{{ Form::text('TP_tr_from_date_multicity', null, array('type' => 'text','data-date-format'=>"yyyy-mm-dd", 'class' => 'form-control datepicker','name'=>'TP_tr_from_date_multicity_1','id' => 'TravelFromDate_1','placeholder'=>'* Travel Start Date','title'=>'Pick the travelling start date')) }}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Am cloning this tr by

```
var select = $("#CloneThisTR").clone(true);
```

I want to change each id with _1 like TR_FromCities_1 to TR_FromCities_2 
or TR_ToCities_1 to TR_ToCities_2 etc.

How it can be done using find()?

Comment: While this is possible, using `id` attributes on cloned elements is normally an anti-pattern as it becomes a very big pain to maintain. For example, you have to re-number all the rows when one in the middle is removed. A better alternative would be to use a common class on all the rows and then traverse the DOM to perform any required actions by the row index.

Comment: Actually I will be using sortable on this. So if there is any change in location after sort then it may fail .

Comment: Can't we change it while cloning? I think we can change. but am not able to to. I tried but it was not working .

Answer (score 0):

Here, get the id of the cloned tr, the split with `_` .
TR_FromCities_1 should give ["TR","FromCities","1"]
get the last element of array,convert to int and increment it by one. convert it back to string and replace in the last array index. Join and set the id for the clone!

```
        var id = $select.attr('id') || null;
        if(id) {
           var spl = beforeID.split("_");
           var i=(parseInt(spl[spl.length-1])+1).toString();
           spl[spl.length-1]=i;
           $select.attr('id', spl.join("_"));
        }
```

for all td in the cloned tr!

```
$select.find('td').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id') || null;
        if(id) {
           var spl = beforeID.split("_");
           var i=(parseInt(spl[spl.length-1])+1).toString();
           spl[spl.length-1]=i;
           $select.attr('id', spl.join("_"));
        }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes your are right. But this will work If i want to change for one ID.
But I want to traverse whole cloned TR and change ID of each

Comment: I've made the edits! hope that answers your question.